# dot notation with p for hexadecimal numeric literals in swift

Tags: swift

I'm working through the first basic playground in https://github.com/nettlep/learn-swift  using XCode

What exactly is happening with this expression?

```
0xC.3p0 == 12.1875
```

I've learned about hexadecimal literals and the special "p" notation that indicates a power of 2.

```
0xF == 15

0xFp0 == 15   //  15 * 2^0
```

If I try `0xC.3` I get the error: Hexadecimal floating point literal must end with an exponent.

I found this nice [overview of numeric literals](http://www.codingexplorer.com/integers-and-numeric-literals-in-swift/) and [another deep explanation](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/), but I didn't see something that explains what `.3p0` does.

I've forked the code and upgraded this lesson to XCode 7 / Swift 2 -- here's the [specific line](https://github.com/ultrasaurus/learn-swift/blob/xcode7/1a.%20The%20Basics.playground/Contents.swift#L208).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Hexadecimal exponential notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Hexadecimal_exponential_notation).

> By convention, the letter P (or p, for "power") represents **times two
>   raised to the power of** ... The number after the P is decimal and
>   represents the binary exponent.
>
> ...
>
> Example: 1.3DEp42 represents hex(1.3DE) × dec(2^42).

For your example, we get:

```
0xC.3p0 represents 0xC.3 * 2^0 = 0xC.3 * 1 = hex(C.3) = 12.1875

where hex(C.3) = dec(12.{3/16}) = dec(12.1875)
```

As an example, you can try `0xC.3p1` (equals `hex(C.3) * dec(2^1)`), which yields double the value, i.e., `24.375`.

You can also study the binary exponent growth in a playground for hex-value 1:

```
// ...
print(0x1p-3) // 1/8 (0.125)
print(0x1p-2) // 1/4 (0.25)
print(0x1p-1) // 1/2 (0.5)
print(0x1p1) // 2.0
print(0x1p2) // 4.0
print(0x1p3) // 8.0
// ...
```

---

Finally, this is also explained in [Apple`s Language Reference - Lexical Types: Floating-Point Literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/hexadecimal-literal):

> Hexadecimal floating-point literals consist of a 0x prefix, followed
>   by an optional hexadecimal fraction, **followed by a hexadecimal
>   exponent**. The hexadecimal fraction consists of a decimal point
>   followed by a sequence of hexadecimal digits. **The exponent consists
>   of an upper- or lowercase p prefix followed by a sequence of decimal
>   digits that indicates what power of 2 the value preceding the p is
>   multiplied by**. For example, 0xFp2 represents 15 x 2^2, which
>   evaluates to 60. Similarly, 0xFp-2 represents 15 x 2^-2, which
>   evaluates to 3.75.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation.  The thing that threw me off was that 0xC.3 was not allowed, which distracted me from recognizing it as a hexidecimal fraction.  Given the grammar in the Apple reference, seems like that error could be a bug?

Comment: @Ultrasaurus You're welcome. I can see how that threw you off, it can be a bit strange if you're traversed with hexadecimal numbers but not, specifically, hex. exponential notation. I'd say that that the error is expected behaviour though, as documentation (above) states *"... consist of a 0x prefix, followed by an optional hexadecimal fraction, followed by a hexadecimal exponent."*; i.e., the hexadecimal exponent needs to be present for a complete floating-point literal in hexadecimal format. ... <next comment>

Comment: ... From documentation, look for *"floating-point-literal"* under *"Grammar of a floating-point literal"*: if we want to use hexadecimal notation, the floating-point must be presented on form *hexadecimal-literal­ Optional(hexadecimal-fraction­) ­hexadecimal-exponent­*. The latter, *hex-exp*, is mandatory for this representation; hence excluding it will result in compile time error.

Comment: By logic it doesn't make any sense to make 'p' or 'P' mean multiplication by 2 to the power of .... Instead it should be 16 just as 10 in decimal, 2 in binary, 8 in octal. So what makes it mean 2?